# Как на концептуальном уровне/(изнутри) работает Websocket

Tags: сокет, websocket

Разбираюсь с Websocket. В книгах Moden operating system и Компьютерные сети не нашел информации. Суть вопроса: когда мы создаем серверный сокет (например в Python) у него еcть метод .accept() который проверяет буфер (как в unix мне легче представлять, что это просто файл) на нашей машине и вернет нам АДРЕС и объект клиентского сокета. Дк вот, что внутри себя представляет этот объект, если у нас уже есть адрес клиента который подключился к нашему серверу?

Это новый файл/буфер в который мы будем записывать ответ и читать полученные данные, а уже операционная система будет давать указатель на этот файл сетевой карте и она будет отправлять данные по сети клиенту

Comment: Так вопрос про socket или про websocket? Это принципиально разные вещи

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за замечание, вопрос про Websocket, но думаю чтобы пояснить работу этой более высокоуровневой абстракции, надеюсь что будет дан ответ и по сокетам

Comment: да это прото немного переделанный http (хорошо-хорошо, сильно переделанный). а то, что вас интересует (наколько я понял) — уровень ниже протокола http (хорошо-хорошо, протокола websocket) — это старый добрый tcp. уж про tcp-то просто мегатонны книг написаны. читайте наздоровье. // ну а если я вас неправильно понял, то полнее и понятнее, чем в [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), про протокол вряд ли кто-либо где-либо напишет.